# What is a "fixed wing" aircraft?

Tags: terminology, fixed-wing

I’ve been trying out different hobbies over the last year, and plane spotting is my current one.

I’ve heard some terms being thrown around about planes like the ones at the Airport - what is a Fixed Wing aircraft please?

Any examples would be good too.

Comment: Have you googled the term "fixed-wing aircraft"? Or checked [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-wing_aircraft)?

Comment: This does not seem to be your first account. If you have lost access to your previous one(s), you can ask them to be merged by using the contact form: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/contact

Answer (score 3):

Fixed Wing is an "airplane".
Rotary Wing is a "helicopter".

The wings (lifting surface), either spin relative to the body, or are attached ("fixed") to the body.

Comment: don't forget gliders (sailplanes) --

Comment: An airplane is a *type* of fixed-wing aircraft, but the terms are not synonymous. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-wing_aircraft#Classes_of_fixed-wing_aircraft).

Comment: IMHO, this guy wasn't asking for the canonical definition.   He seems to want a basic understanding of the term.  For a beginner, fixed==airplane is a pretty good approximation.

Comment: Autogiros are rotary-wing aircraft, but they **are not** helicopters...

Comment: I think this summary is good, given the level at which the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed wing is a kind of heavier than air aircraft which uses fixed i.e. non-moving wings and other lifting services attached to the air frame and forward motion to generate lift. Examples include airplanes, gliders, powered lift aircraft, ultralights, powered parachute and weight shift controlled aircraft.

Rotary wing aircraft are heavier than air aircraft which generate lift by means of lifting surfaces attached to, and rotating about, a central shaft.  They can either be under power and driven by an engine, or auto rotating in airflow moving through the rotor disk. Examples include helicopters, gyroplanes, and powered lift.

Comment: Powered parachute is *not* fixed-wing. Fixed wing means rigid structure permanently attached while in flight. Parachutes are ram-air pressurised wings without rigid structure which strictly depend on flying through air to maintain their airfoil shape, and have no rigid attachment points either, rather they have suspension lines where the payload's relation to the wings changes significantly throughout the flight envelope.

Comment: @mathrick I think that’s arguable; since a powered parachute typically has no fuselage it’s not clear what the wing isn’t fixed to.  It’s reasonable to say that the aircraft *is* the wing, with a payload suspended below it.  What constitutes a rigid structure is open to debate, not least in high-performance paraglider design.

Comment: @Frog: it's certainly fuzzy. I suppose a parachute has more in common with a Cessna than a Eurocopter does when it comes to how the lift is generated, but it has far less in common with it than a Eurocopter when it comes to just about everything else about the craft, including how it reacts to things like turbulence. By that definition, I'm a fixed-wing aircraft when I wingsuit, and I board another fixed-wing aircraft when I deploy my parachute :)

Comment: As defined by whom, mathrick?

Comment: Re "powered parachute" -- I'd call that a "floppy wing aircraft", for sure.  Just as a pure paraglider is often called a "collapse-o-matic".  The floppy-wing concept may arguably even include conventional flex-wing hang gliders and trikes, due to their inherent reliance on shape-shifting for roll control.  Even rigid-wing hang gliders and trikes (e.g. ATOS, and trikes based on similar wings) are arguably *not* fixed-wing aircraft, because the wing is obviously not fixed in relation to the pilot, or to the trike body.

Comment: Um… yeah.  Wow.  First time I’ve ever heard a powered parachute referred to as a fixed wing aircraft.  I guess by that criteria an unpowered parachute is a sailplane?  Learning all kinds of new things here.

Comment: Just as a pure paraglider is often called a "collapse-o-matic"  -- kind of a riff on Cessna's "land-o-matic" concept   : )

Comment: Well there’s no Requirement that a fixed wing aircraft use a solid wing.

Comment: No, but a certain rigidity is implied in the name.  Anyway, nobody is arguing about "requirements", this is about aviation parlance. Above you asked "as defined by whom...?" Well, examples abound of fixed wing aircraft that are NOT powered parachutes, it would seem the burden of proof is on the person making the assertion. 
 So far it's you and whoever wrote the Wikipedia entry. And for purposes of airman certification the FAA considers them in a category of their own. I consider that fact significant.  And why the desire to even lump them with conventional fixed wing? They are SO different.

Comment: From the first two hits for Fixed:  "fastened securely in position."  "securely placed or fastened, stationary."  Kinda hard to make that claim about a loose bit of fabric don't you think?  About the only way it makes sense is if the choice is strictly binary; i.e opposite of rotary wing.  I'll stop now.  Internet debates rarely change minds.  I know mine is made up!  ;)  Cheers.

Comment: If we are to say that heavier-than-air aircraft are either fixed or rotor wing then paragliders and similar aircraft fall into the fixed wing category.  If we admit flexwing as a seperate type (which is omitted from the OP) then paragliders are clearly flexwing and we may continue to debate the taxonomy of aircraft with somewhat fixed and somewhat flexible wings.  Ultimately the definitions are set by usage, which is established by lively discussion on SE :-)

Comment: While not sourced, Wikipedia gives this definition which I agree with.  See below.

Comment: “A fixed-wing aircraft is a heavier-than-air flying machine which is capable of flight using wings that generate lift caused by the aircraft's forward airspeed and the shape of the wings. Fixed-wing aircraft are distinct from rotary-wing aircraft (in which the wings form a rotor mounted on a spinning shaft or "mast"), and ornithopters (in which the wings flap in a manner similar to that of a bird). The wings on fixed-wing aircraft aren’t necessarily rigid; kites, hang gliders, variable-sweep wing aircraft and airplanes that use wing morphing are all examples of fixed-wing aircraft.”

Comment: So yes, there are zero requirements that a fixed wing aircraft have rigid wings in order to be considered such.

Comment: But is there a reason why you feel it is useful to group things that are so incredibly dissimilar?  Because while my question about a free falling parachute being equated to a sailplane was admittedly facetious, a compelling comparison can be made.  P.S.  I happen to disagree with the Wikipedia entry so much that I might for the very first time foray into contributing rather than simply consuming information...

Comment: @Frog, Yes, "if we are to say..." or as I mentioned, if the choice is binary and we are forced to choose.  Because it definitely isn't a rotary wing.  If I had a bunch of mammals, birds, and fish and had to put them in two categories I would group the mammals and birds together because they are both air breathing.  But I would far rather group them in three distinct sets, wouldn't you?!  It just makes way more sense...

Comment: In that case, write your own answer Michael.

Comment: Will you guys give me a break...?  Sheesh!